# What does laravel means by drivers in its authentication module?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

1)Laravel has a very good built in authentication system/module.I had read its documentation the confusion to me is what is definition of a driver in guard and provider?

2)Is defining a new guard means defining a new driver?

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration defining a new **Guard** is defining a coupling of a driver and a provider. In the default setup the Guard `web` is the `session` driver and the `users` provider used together. The driver is the means of actually figuring out the user from a request and the provider is the interface to the records, in simplest terms.

At the class level a **Guard** is what the configuration refers to as a Driver.

```
namespace Illuminate\Auth;

class TokenGuard implements Guard
```

is the `token` driver in the `api` guard in the config.

```
namespace Illuminate\Auth;

class SessionGuard implement StatefulGuard, ...
```

is the `session` driver in the `web` guard.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Comment: But what if I want to use same driver but a different provider... Will it be same as defining a new *Gaurd*

Comment: in the context of the `guards` array in the `config/auth.php` file, it would be a guard, in regards to the `auth` middleware and the `guard` method of the `AuthManager` that is what 'guard' means